# Issue with List Display in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm facing a problem when trying to display a list in Python within PyCharm. I have the following code:

```
friends = [['John', 25, 'Cancer'], ['Maria', 23, 'Aries'], ['Ana', 31, 'Aquarius']]
friends[2].append('juazeiro')
print(friends)
```

The code looks correct to me, but when I run it in PyCharm, the output I get is just "Process finished with exit code 0," and the list is not displayed. I would like to understand why this is happening and how I can get the list to be printed correctly in the output.

I have checked my syntax, and I don't see any apparent errors. The PyCharm console is open, but the list is not being displayed. Is there any specific PyCharm setting that might be causing this issue?

I appreciate in advance any help or guidance you can provide.

Thank you!

I tried to run the provided Python code in PyCharm, and I expected it to display the list friends after appending the string 'juazeiro' to the third element of the list. However, what actually resulted was that the code executed successfully without any errors, but the list was not displayed. Instead, the PyCharm output just showed "Process finished with exit code 0."

Comment: Are you sure that you execute the right python module in Pycharm? You can check it in the execution configuration

Comment: Use a [debugger and breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html).

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is correct, and the "Process finished with exit code 0" message you're seeing in PyCharm indicates that your code ran without any errors. Try to run this code in Terminal via `python3 script_name.py` and I think you will get printed list.

OR you can select your code, click right button and choose `Execute Selection in Python Console`.